# Select data from JSON output for insert statement in Python

Tags: python, sql, json, oracle

Suppose I have a JSON like this:

```
[
 {
  "randomcol" : "randomvarchar"
 }
]
```

And it is generated like this:

```
cursor_orcl.execute("""
                    Select * from test_t where 
            """)

rows = cursor_orcl.fetchall()
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor_orcl.description]
result = []

for row in rows:
    row = dict(zip(columns, row))
    result.append(row)
```

I need to generate insert SQL statement in Python from this. I came up with the following:

```
...
cursor_insert = cnxn.cursor()
cursor_insert.arraysize= 50000
sql = (
    "INSERT INTO dbo.test_t (randomcol) " + " VALUES("
    "SELECT randomcol" +
    "FROM OPENJSON(?))"
      )

cursor_insert.execute(sql)   
cursor_insert.close ()
cnxn.commit ()
```

However it is giving me this error: **'pyodbc.Error: ('07002'. '[07002]' [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')'**

What could be wrong? This is just test table with only 1 row/column, I do not understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle, syntax like you used is invalid; remove `values` keyword.

```
insert into test_t (randomcol) values (select randomcol from openjson)
                               ------
                               remove it!
```

Brackets can also be removed, so - finally - you'd get

```
insert into test_t (randomcol) select randomcol from openjson
```

Comment: It is giving me " Invalid object name 'openjson'".  I am trying to insert in SQL Server (v18.4). I found out it could be due to insufficient compatability, it is set to 150 in my case, so that should not be an issue? So frustrating

Comment: "Invalid object name" looks like the table named `openjson` doesn't exist. You're selecting from it, so - check whether it exists or not. Mind letter case (if it matters).

Comment: I have added how I generate JSON , and  in my case I would need to get values from 'result ' which contains data in JSON format. Sorry I am new to this, so it's somewhat difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can load in JSON strings as dictionaries to Python.

```
import json
yourdict = json.loads({"randomcol":"randomstring"})
```

After that you can work with it like any normal python dictionary.